# Android Button background states with unexpected behaviour

Tags: android

I have a `Button` with a backround ressource that defines states and backgrounds

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/white" android:state_pressed="true"  />
    <item android:drawable="@color/gray" android:state_pressed="false"  />

    <item android:drawable="@color/white" android:state_selected="true"  />
    <item android:drawable="@color/gray" android:state_selected="false"  />

</selector>
```

I also tried

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/white" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/gray" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"  />

</selector>
```

when pressed it does change colors, but when I apply `btn.setSelected(true);` nothing happens

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `btn.performClick();`, which clicks the button. This might work:

```
void pressButton(Button btn, boolean pressed) {
    if (pressed != btn.isPressed()) {
        btn.performClick();
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, how about btn.performClick()? See my modified answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK I got it,

for future people who will encounter this, this has solved it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/white" android:state_pressed="true"  />
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" android:state_selected="true"  />
    <item android:drawable="@color/tab_gray" />

</selector>
```